# Paste function modifying other sheets

Tags: excel, paste, selected

I am trying to copy the format of the first row to all the rows that are filled up with data. After that, the rest of the rows (empty) are deleted.

Normally this should be done with the sheet not selected. The code below works good, except when the user has both other sheets and the xsInvestmentSummary jointly selected. In that case, when pasting, the other sheets are also modified.

I don't understand why. In this code, all refers to xsInvestmentSummary.

```
With xsInvestmentSummary
    If .Cells(FilaTitulo + 3, 1).Value <> "" Then

        Set CeldaInicio = .Cells(FilaTitulo + 2, 1)
        Set CeldaFin = CeldaInicio.End(xlDown)
        .Cells(FilaTitulo + 1, 1).EntireRow.Copy
        .Range(CeldaInicio, CeldaFin).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats ' After this line, the other selected sheets are modified

        Set CeldaInicio = .Cells(CeldaFin.Row + 1, 1)
        Set CeldaFin = CeldaInicio.End(xlDown)
        .Range(CeldaInicio, CeldaFin).EntireRow.Delete

    End If
End With
```

Comment: You are saying that "when the user has both other sheets and the xsInvestmentSummary jointly selected"; In this case you can select just one sheet before running the function i.e. you can call Sheets(sheet_name).Activate before rest of the code

Comment: Agreed, i don't think the problem is in this part of the code.

Comment: That is the solution, and it is what I don't want to do. I mean, this code runs automatically when the user saves the file. That Sheet is a report sheet, so the user normally doesn't work on it. If the user is working on other sheet, and has several selected (for whatever reason), and saves the file, then the other sheets get damaged.

Comment: Yes, the code seems ok to me too, but when debugging, the sheet gets damaged when running the "PasteSpecial" line.